# how to understand this recursion in the leecode?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

new to java,I read the answer in the leecode ,and it ask for a array like [1,2,3]and return its permutation [1,3,2],[2,1,3].....and feel confused especially this code

```
Collections.swap(output, first, i);
backtrack(n, output, res, first + 1);
```

I do not know why the use Collections.swap(output,first,i) I think in first loop ,the first and i is equal to 0,so why use swap here. they are same vaule. what this recursion actually do,I debug it and can not figure out.code is below:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

 class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]arr=new int[]{1,2,3};
    Main main1=new Main();
    List<List<Integer>> lists = main1.permute(arr);
    System.out.println(lists);

}

   public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
       List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

       List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for (int num : nums) {
           output.add(num);
       }

       int n = nums.length;
       backtrack(n, output, res, 0);
       return res;
   }

   public void backtrack(int n, List<Integer> output, List<List<Integer>> res, int first) {
       
       if (first == n) {
           res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(output));
       }
       for (int i = first; i < n; i++) {
           
           Collections.swap(output, first, i);
          
           backtrack(n, output, res, first + 1);
          
           Collections.swap(output, first, i);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are yo asking what `Collections.swap` does ?

Comment: @c0der I am confused about the permutaion does, Navaneeth Sen make the Collections.swap clear,but I do not know the method in the permutatin

Comment: @c0der ok but it take me some time to read your code

Comment: every time I use  backtrack(n, output, res, first + 1) then it go to function backtrck ,so it is  Collections.swap(output, first, i); and the  fist =i beacause of "int i = first" in the for loop. so why get  [1,2,3] > swap to [1,3,2]. lol .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237111/discussion-between-zzzbei-and-c0der).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat simplified and commented version that may help follow what the code does:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main   {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]arr=new int[]{1,2,3};
        List<List<Integer>> permutations = new Main().permute(arr);
        System.out.println(permutations);
    }

       public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {

           List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
           List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
           for (int num : nums) {
               input.add(num);
           }

           backtrack(input, result, 0);
           return result;
       }

       public void backtrack(List<Integer> input, List<List<Integer>> result, int currentIndex) {

           if (currentIndex == input.size() ) { //index passed the end of the collection
               result.add(new ArrayList<>(input)); //add the permutation to the returned result
               //the method return here because when currentIndex == input.size()
               //next for loop will not be executed
               //you may add a return here. It may improve the readability of the code
           }

           //iterate over each element of the array form currentIndex to the end
           for (int i = currentIndex; i < input.size(); i++) {

               Collections.swap(input, currentIndex, i);//create a permutation by swapping

               backtrack(input, result, currentIndex + 1); //increment currentIndex and process new permutation

               Collections.swap(input, currentIndex, i);//undo permutation before next loop
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: it seems the last "Collections.swap(input, currentIndex, i);//undo permutation before next loop" never excute

Comment: It does, when `backtrack(input, result, currentIndex + 1);` returns. Add a simple printout to see.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)), the swap() method of java.util.Collections class is used to swap the elements at the specified positions in the specified list. **If the specified positions are equal, invoking this method leaves the list unchanged.**

So in a recursive technique, it is ok to have that call even though it does nothing in that particular condition, just to make the logic easier to implement and understand. If you want to avoid that, you will un-necessarily need to bring conditional statements into the logic, which is really not required.

Comment: but ,I find each recursion in the backtrack(n,output,res,first+1),the Collection.swap(output,first,i)will get the same result. why this make the permutation successly?

Comment: It swaps to elements in the list to get a new permutation. For example  [1,2,3] > swap to [1,3,2]